# Return values from completion handler

Tags: swift

I want to return the values from an api call.

The call to my api class (I want to get the values in res):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let t = Api_test();
        let res = t.getSomething();

        print(res)
    }
}
```

The api class:

```
import Foundation

class Api_test {

     func getAllStations(completionHandler: (response : XMLIndexer) -> ()) {

    getRequest { result in
        completionHandler(response: SWXMLHash.parse(result))
    };
}

    func getRequest(completionHandler: (result: NSData) -> ()) {
        let baseUrl = "http://api.test.com"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: baseUrl)!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if data == nil {
                print("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(error)")
                return
            } else {
                completionHandler(result: data!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Everything works as thought, but I'm stuck at the point to return the values back to the getSomething function. The data is in xml format. How can I get the result set as returned values in the res (viewDidLoad)?

Comment: Do you want to make the entire program wait till you get the response from `getRequest` function?

Comment: Pass a completion closure to `getSomething`? You can then call it within `getResult`'s completion handler.

Comment: @ozgur Yes, because the program needs the data. Or should I run the entire class on another thread?

Comment: @originaluser2 How can Perform that?

Comment: @da1lbi3 Have your `getSomething` take a `(whateverTypeYourDataIs) -> ()` closure, and call it from within the `getRequest` completion closure. Literally exactly the same as what you're doing with `getRequest`. As a general rule, you shouldn't have your program waiting for something unless it really has to, and even then it should never wait on the main thread. Although it's pretty hard to advise based on what you've told us, could you give a little more context on what you're actually trying to do here?

Comment: @originaluser2 Ok, I have changed the code, can you check if it's right?:)

Comment: @da1lbi3 Sure, I don't see anything wrong with it (except you'll need to update your view controller code to pass a completion block into it) – you're the one testing it though! Does it work?

Comment: @originaluser2 Yes it works. Thank you very much! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSURLSession` is a fully asynchronous networking API so ideally your view controller should operate correctly and not wait for the data to be returned from the network.

You have three options here:

1. You can pass a completion block to `getSomething` and have it pass the result to the block:

   ```
   func getSomething(completionHandler: (result: XMLIndexer) -> ()) {
     getRequest { result in
       completionHandler(result: SWXMLHash.parse(result))
     }
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     ...
     t.getSomething { res in
       print(res)
     }
   }
   ```
2. If you desperately need the XML data in hand before view is displayed onto screen, you can make the main thread wait till network operation finishes executing. You can use [`dispatch_semaphore_t`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_semaphore_signal):

   ```
   func getSomething() -> XMLIndexer? {
     var xml: XMLIndexer? = nil
     let semaphore: dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
     getRequest { result in
       xml = SWXMLHash.parse(result)
       dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
     }
     dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
     return xml
   }
   ```
3. Last option is, you can use another 3rd party that does the parsing  synchronously. There is a great one named [`Ono`](https://github.com/mattt/Ono):

   ```
   var error: NSError?
   let xml = ONOXMLDocument(data: result, error: &error)
   ```

Comment: I agree completely with this answer... except method 2. You really shouldn't ever wait on the main thread ever. It's a bad idea from both a programming and UX point of view. I would highly recommend simply doing an asynchronous request and showing a loading message to the user while it happens (this can be displayed over the view). That way the user doesn't freak out and think the app just froze.

Comment: I know, this is why I said ideally the view controller should operate correctly until the data is returned from the network. I am just telling there is a way to do it, not telling he should do it.

Comment: Ah okay, skimmed over your first paragraph slightly there, my bad! Although actually thinking about it now, `dispatch_sync` won't wait for the request to finish anyway as the `getResult` method itself is asynchronous. You'd have to use a semaphore instead, although the same health warnings still apply.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I will update my code accordingly. I totally overlooked the fact that getRequest will return immediately within the dispatch block. Semaphore or dispatch_group is needed there. Thanks for finding that out!